# ultimative find command in bash to trace all illegal and unknown chars and symbols in filenames

Tags: bash, find, filenames

Many similar solutions can be found to detect or change "illegal" characters in filenames.
Most solutions require you to know the illegal characters.
A solution to find those filenames often ends with something like:

`find . -name "*[\+\;\"\\\=\?\~\<\>\&\*\|\$\'\,\{\}\%\^\#\:\(\)]*"`

This is already quite good, but sometimes there are cryptic characters (e.g. h͔͉̝e̻̦l̝͍͓l̢͚̻o͇̝̘w̙͇͜o͔̼͚r̝͇̞l̘̘d̪͔̝.̟͔̠t͉͖̼x̟̞t̢̝̦ or ʇxʇ.pʅɹoʍoʅʅǝɥ or © or €), symbols, or characters from other character sets in my file names. I can not trace these files this way. Inverse lookarounds or the find command with regex is probably the right approach, but I don't get anywhere.

In other words: Find all filenames which do NOT match the following pattern [^a-zA-Z0-9 ._-] would be perfect. Mostly [:alnum:] but with regex the command would be more flexibel.

`find . ! -name [^a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]` does not do the job. Any idea?

I use bash or zsh on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```bash
find . -name '*[!a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]*'
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work great. How can I also add  (or escape) ' as an allowed character?

Comment: Since I am now able to find many "false" characters (e.g. German Special Chars) like ü which is not the regular ü which I meanwhile added to the regex `(*[!a-zA-Z0-9:()\[\]äöüÄÖÜß ._-]*)` but indeed it is unicode: u<0308>.
The find command `find . -name '*u<0308>*'` can handle unicode trace, but the zmv command I normally use to rename unwanted filenames fails with Unicode Character 'COMBINING DIAERESIS' (U+0308).
`zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#qD.)' '$f:gs/ü/ue'`
any additional idea?

Comment: FWIW `-name` doesn't take a regex, it takes a pattern defined by [fnmatch()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch). `find . -regex`, however, takes a regex.

Comment: However `find . -regex` seems not to work here (zsh@OSX)...?
I finally ended up with `find . -name '*[!a-zA-Z0-9()\[\]äöüÄÖÜß ._-]*' -a -not -name '*['\'']*'` which lists all filenames containing illegal chars & symbols ignoring filenames containing "normal" UTF-8 chars like: a-zA-Z0-9()\[\]äöüÄÖÜß ._- and single quotes.